# wordpress - how to add logo on menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I am creating my custom theme, but I cannot find any option which allow me to create logo on the left on menu bar

[image]

My current Menu:
[image]

I want to add the logo here:
[image]

Appearance > Theme Editor > header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="xxxxx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <?php 
    wp_head(); 
    ?>
</head>

</html>

<body <?php body_class('bg'); ?>>
    <?php wp_body_open(); ?>
```

Comment: I dont think wordpress supports that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick is to use the image HTML in the custom link:

[image]

With this it will show the image at the menu mentioned:

[image]